# Simulate a cell like in between two cells and below two cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

[image]

I am using tableview and collection view inside to create this screen.

If you look closer in the design..i will have to create an effect of cells going above below or top cell with a corner radius...which simulates like the cells are below and in between two cells...

The same goes for the top area which has a corner radius.

Please guide through a proper way to design this entire screen.

(I am using storyboard and UIKit only...i dont want to use swiftUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways to approach this -- here's one...

Four cell types:

- "Top" cell
- "Categories" cell
- "Top Products" cell
- "Suggestions" cell

In each cell class, add a `UIView` with rounded corners - this will hold the "content" of each cell.

***Behind*** the rounded corners view, add a "Top Color" `UIView` and a a "Bottom Color" `UIView`.

It looks like this:

[image]

When running, we get this result:

[image]

Here is some sample code:

```
class MyBaseCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var topBotColors: [UIColor] = [.white, .white] {
        didSet {
            topColorView.backgroundColor = topBotColors[0]
            botColorView.backgroundColor = topBotColors[1]
        }
    }
    
    let theStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 12
        return v
    }()
    
    let topColorView = UIView()
    let botColorView = UIView()
    let roundedCornerView = UIView()
    
    var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var botConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        [topColorView, botColorView, roundedCornerView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }

        theStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        roundedCornerView.addSubview(theStack)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        topConstraint = theStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0)
        botConstraint = theStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            topColorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            topColorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            topColorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),

            botColorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topColorView.bottomAnchor),
            botColorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topColorView.heightAnchor),
            
            botColorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            botColorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            botColorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

            roundedCornerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            roundedCornerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            roundedCornerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            roundedCornerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),

            theStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.leadingAnchor),
            theStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.trailingAnchor),

            topConstraint, botConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

}

class TopCell: MyBaseCell {
    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
        
        // let's add 1 tall label
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "Top Cell"
        v.textColor = .white
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .bold)
        theStack.addArrangedSubview(v)

        // avoid auot-layout complaints
        let c = v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        c.isActive = true
    }
}

class CatsCell: MyBaseCell {
    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
        
        // let's add a few labels
        for i in 1...4 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.text = "Categories Label \(i)"
            theStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        roundedCornerView.backgroundColor = .white
        roundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 24
    }
}

class TopProdsCell: MyBaseCell {
    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
        
        // let's add a few labels
        for i in 1...3 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.text = "Top Prods Label \(i)"
            v.textColor = .white
            theStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        roundedCornerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        // increase top/bottom "spacing"
        topConstraint.constant = 24.0
        botConstraint.constant = -24.0
    }
}

class SuggestionsCell: MyBaseCell {
    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
        
        // let's add a few labels
        for i in 1...6 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.text = "Suggested Label \(i)"
            theStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        roundedCornerView.backgroundColor = .white
        roundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 24
    }
}

class SampleTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    let myGray: UIColor = .gray
    let myBlue: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.30, blue: 0.65, alpha: 1.0)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(TopCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "topCell")
        tableView.register(CatsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "catCell")
        tableView.register(TopProdsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "prodCell")
        tableView.register(SuggestionsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "suggCell")
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        let bkv = UIView()
        bkv.backgroundColor = myGray
        tableView.backgroundView = bkv
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath) as! TopCell
            c.topBotColors = [myGray, myGray]
            return c
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "catCell", for: indexPath) as! CatsCell
            c.topBotColors = [myGray, myBlue]
            return c
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prodCell", for: indexPath) as! TopProdsCell
            c.topBotColors = [myBlue, myBlue]
            return c
        }
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "suggCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestionsCell
        c.topBotColors = [myBlue, myGray]
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate the effort taken to answer the question...no words bro..thank you so much